# Words are colored after pressing the space key on the keyboard. I would like to color them immediately after the last letter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with a Javascript script to color text. There are strings set for coloring, but the word is only colored when I press the "space" key on the keyboard. If i write the word, it doesn't color. If I write the word and press the space key it becomes colored.

I would like to color the word immediately as i write it, without waiting to press the space button. For example, i set that `HELLO` should be colored. I would like it to color immediately as soon as I finish pressing the final `O`, and not when i type `HELLO`  (with a final space).

The problem occurs when you try to manually write something in the code panel, for example if you write Hello. The problem lies in the `changeColor()` function, there is a `Keyup Event` and a `Space Key Pressed`.

I tried to remove the part of the code that concerns the EventListener("keyup"... and the keycode, but everything breaks and doesn't work. I am new to Javascript, I can't solve it.

**index.html**

```
  <div id="editor" contenteditable="true" oninput="showPreview();" onchange="changeColor();">&lt;h1>This is a Heading&lt;/h1>
    &lt;p>This is a paragraph.&lt;/p>
  </div>
    
    <h3>PREVIEW</h3>
    <div class="preview-area">
      <iframe id="preview-window"></iframe>
    </div>
```

**style.css**

```
#editor {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
.statement {
  color: orange;
}
```

**javascript.js**

```
function applyColoring(element) {
    var keywords = ["DIV", "DIV", "H1", "H1", "P", "P", "HELLO", "<", ">", "/"];
  
    var newHTML = "";
    // Loop through words
    str = element.innerText;
    (chunks = str
      .split(new RegExp(keywords.map((w) => `(${w})`).join("|"), "i"))
      .filter(Boolean)),
      (markup = chunks.reduce((acc, chunk) => {
        acc += keywords.includes(chunk.toUpperCase())
          ? `<span class="statement">${chunk}</span>`
          : `<span class='other'>${chunk}</span>`;
        return acc;
      }, ""));
    element.innerHTML = markup;
  }
  


  // CHANGE COLOR 
  function changeColor() {
    // Keyup event
    document.querySelector("#editor").addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
      // Space key pressed
      if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        applyColoring(e.target);
  
        // Set cursor postion to end of text
        //    document.querySelector('#editor').focus()
        var child = e.target.children;
        var range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range.setStart(child[child.length - 1], 1);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        this.focus();
      }
    });
  }
  
changeColor()
applyColoring(document.getElementById('editor'));


//PREVIEW
function showPreview() {
    var editor = document.getElementById("editor").innerText;
  
    // var cssCode =
    //  "<style>" + document.getElementById("cssCode").value + "</style>";
    // var jsCode =
    //  "<scri" + "pt>" + document.getElementById("jsCode").value + "</scri" + "pt>";
    
    var frame = document.getElementById("preview-window").contentWindow.document;
    document.getElementById("preview-window").srcdoc = editor;
    frame.open();
    //frame.write(htmlCode + cssCode + jsCode);
    frame.write(editor);
    frame.close();
  }
  
  showPreview()
```

Comment: You said you're new to JavaScript. I take it this was written by ChatGPT?

Comment: @NkemdiAnyiam No. I found the code in an old question here on StackOverflow and customized it a bit.

Comment: `I would like it to color immediately as soon as I finish pressing the final O` so, not when you press the H or E or L ... only when you press O ... what about other words? is this just for HELLO? because otherwise, how can you know that the last letter of a word has been typed? perhaps you're typing HELL ... but using your described logic the colour won't be applied as you haven't pressed the O

Comment: @JaromandaX You are right to think this, perhaps I expressed myself poorly. HELLO is just one example. I was referring to the last letter of whatever text is written

Comment: See, the way you say it, the word does not get coloured BEFORE the last letter is typed, only once it is typed - so, How do you determine what the last letter is?

Comment: @JaromandaX When I talk about the last letter, it was just an example to make you understand what I meant. The code does not have to detect the last letter exactly. In reality it is not literally a question of the last letter, but it is a question of the completeness of the word. The way to determine the word is var keywords = ["DIV", "DIV", "H1", "H1", "P", "P", "HELLO", "<", ">", "/ "].

Comment: Oh, so it's only a few select words that are colours ... got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track: you don't have to delete the whole 'keyup' event listener code—just remove the if-statement surrounding the logic. The `if (e.keyCode == 32)` checks to see if the Space key was pressed, so if you want that part of the code to run when *any* key is pressed, simply don't use the if-statement.

```
function changeColor() {
    // Keyup event
    document.querySelector("#editor").addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
      // // Space key pressed
      // if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        applyColoring(e.target);
  
        // Set cursor postion to end of text
        //    document.querySelector('#editor').focus()
        var child = e.target.children;
        var range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range.setStart(child[child.length - 1], 1);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        this.focus();
      // }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

to coloring the word immediately after typing the last letter Instead of relying on the `"keyup"` event you can use the `"input"` event
This will allow you to update the color immediately after each letter is typed

Additionally, I've made some adjustments to the applyColoring function for better handling.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        #editor {
            width: 400px;
            height: 100px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #444;
            color: white;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: monospace;
            white-space: pre;
        }

        .statement {
            color: orange;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" oninput="changeColor(); showPreview();">
    &lt;h1>This is a Heading&lt;/h1>
    &lt;p>This is a paragraph.&lt;/p>
</div>

<h3>PREVIEW</h3>
<div class="preview-area">
    <iframe id="preview-window"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
    function applyColoring(element) {
        var keywords = ["DIV", "H1", "P", "HELLO", "<", ">", "/"];

        var newHTML = "";
        // Loop through words
        str = element.innerText;
        (chunks = str
            .split(new RegExp(keywords.map((w) => `(${w})`).join("|"), "i"))
            .filter(Boolean)),
            (markup = chunks.reduce((acc, chunk) => {
                acc += keywords.includes(chunk.toUpperCase())
                    ? `<span class="statement">${chunk}</span>`
                    : `<span class='other'>${chunk}</span>`;
                return acc;
            }, ""));
        element.innerHTML = markup;
    }

    // CHANGE COLOR
    function changeColor() {
        var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
        applyColoring(editor);

        // Set cursor position to the end of text
        var child = editor.children;
        var range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range.setStart(child[child.length - 1], 1);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        editor.focus();
    }

   function showPreview() {
    var editorContent = document.getElementById("editor").innerText;
    var frame = document.getElementById("preview-window");
    
   
    // Create a data URL with the HTML content
    var dataURL = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(editorContent);
    
    // Set the iframe src attribute to the data URL
    frame.src = dataURL;
}
changeColor()

showPreview()

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you're saying I should use your applyColoring function and then I should use the changeColor function suggested by Nkemdi Anyiam?

Comment: Anyway I tried your code, but it doesn't work. Could you double check it please?
​

Comment: I have thoroughly reviewed the code and included an illustrative example. Please let me know if this aligns with your expectations

Comment: Thank you. I read your code. I have some small curiosities. 1) What is the difference between editor.focus() and this.focus()? 2) Why create a data URL with the HTML content? (and consequently frame.src). 3) What happens if I don't create a data URL?

Comment: `editor.focus()` focuses specifically on the element with the ID 'editor', while `this.focus() `is more general, referring to the context where it's used.

Creating a data URL (`frame.srcdoc`) embeds HTML content directly into the URL, enabling dynamic updates to the iframe without server requests.

If you don't use a data URL, you might need server requests to update iframe content dynamically, impacting responsiveness and user experience.